# Add chapter information to existing video with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, video, metadata, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am trying to add chapter markers (text + images) to an existing video in iOS. Reading them is trivially easy with builtin functions:

```cc
NSLocale * locale = [chapterLocalications lastObject];
NSLog(@"Locale: %@", [locale localeIdentifier]);
NSArray *keys = @[AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle, AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork];
NSArray *chapters = [asset chapterMetadataGroupsWithTitleLocale:locale containingItemsWithCommonKeys:keys];
for (AVTimedMetadataGroup * metadataGroup in chapters) {
    NSArray * items = metadataGroup.items;
    CMTimeRange timeRange = metadataGroup.timeRange;
    NSLog(@"time: %@", CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, timeRange.start));
    for (AVMetadataItem * metadataItem in items) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@", metadataItem.commonKey);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", metadataItem.value);
    }
}
```

So far I have not found a way to write timed metadata to a file. I can easily write normal metadata (like title text or pictures) using AVAssetExportSession and AVMutableMetadataItem. There is a AVMutableTimedMetadataGroup, but frustratingly there doesn't seem to be a way to actually write these to a track.

My current thinking is that I need to write chapter information into a temporary file and then use AVMutableComposition to merge the chapter track into the existing video. Of course, that leaves the problem of writing the chapter information. I could write an MP4 container manually or with a third party library (which I'd like to avoid), or I could try to convince AVAssetWriter to somehow write timed metadata tracks, though that is not documented, either. And then I still don't know if AVMutableComposition is able to merge chapter tracks.

Has anyone found a way to do this, before I go mad? I'm tempted to drop this whole chapter idea and just save an application-specific file that references the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a session from Apple's WWDC 2014 called Harnessing Metadata in Audiovisual Media.  Check out the video here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

Also, check out the sample code called [AVTimedAnnotationWriter](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/avtimedannotationwriterusingcustomannotationmetadataformoviewritingandplayback.zip)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, though it uses API only available from iOS 8+ and OSX 10.10+... It looks like the only way on earlier versions is to construct the tracks in memory by building the sample buffers manually. The [avsubtitlewriterOSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/avsubtitleswriterOSX/Introduction/Intro.html) demo shows how, though for now I just created an app-specific format. At least I didn't miss something obvious!